# Custom module express js:Cannot find module name error when modules folder in root directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Folder structure of my express js app look like this[image]

I am  trying to load a `modules` folder  which is located in root directory

**routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var md=require('./modules');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/',function(req, res, next) {
  //res.send('respond with a resource');
  console.log('test');
  res.status(200).json({ error: 'message' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

But i am getting a module not found error:

> Cannot find module './modules'

**Note:**

If `modules` folder is in `node_modules` folder require works fine,but getting module name error if its in project root directory,
also an  `index.js` file is present in `modules` folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module resolution in NodeJS is relative to the directory of your dependent module when your resolution starts with `.`.

In other words :

```
var module = require('../modules'); // Since your file is in `./routes/index` 
                                   // and `module` is in `./modules/index`
```

If you don't supply `.` in front of the required module, then NodeJS will look for that module in `node_modules` directory.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), which is self explanatory.

```
require(X) from module at path Y
1. If X is a core module,
   a. return the core module
   b. STOP
2. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
   a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
   b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(Y + X)
3. LOAD_NODE_MODULES(X, dirname(Y))
4. THROW "not found"
```

So in your case when you `require('./modules')`. NodeJS looks for it in the current directory `./routes`, then since it can't find it, goes to look at it in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of './modules' you can try require('../modules')